# linux audio feedback

Tags: audio, jack

I am using jackd and pulseaudio with the pulseaudio-jack-module so that I can have pulseaudio and jack running at the same time. I mostly use jack applications, except for web browsing and a few other applications.

I am trying to record audio but I get really bad feedback if I try to record audio. If I plug in my headphones the feedback mostly goes away but if I touch the laptop I can hear it in my recording.

It sounds like linux is still recording through my built in mic. I am wondering if I can fix this or will I need to buy a usb mic or something like that?

I am using kxstudio's audio

Here's some debugging output

```
aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, CS4208 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions


aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS4208 Analog [CS4208 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CS4208 Digital [CS4208 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I would just like to be able to record some short clips, not for music or anything, more like a voice over.

I have qas mixer and it [image: looks like this]
In the above screenshot I have headphones plugged in so that I don't blow out my ears.

I made this sample clip, it's very short but you can literally hear my keystrokes and me moving my hands or try to type. You can [listen to the 10 second clip here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0Y7goPD9OzE)

So does this mean that I need a usb mic or is there something wrong with my audio setup? How could I fix this?

Comment: What's the output of ``arecord -l``  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like you're boosting your mic gain; that does make noise more pronounced.

Also, you probably have too many mics active. You should methodically go through each capture option and mute it, and then unmute one-by-one until you identify the one you actually are using.

Comment: Actually if you look there's only one active mic, which is the internal mic. Turning down the gain and it records nothing. If I disable the recording by un-checking that radial button there's no recording at all. Even after I plug in my 3.5mm mic into this laptops 3.5mm jack. I asked this somewhere else but would a usb audio interface allow me to just record with my 3.5mm jack?

Comment: I got a usb dongle with mic and speaker inputs, that solved the problem since I can now have a dedicated mic and dedicated speakers although using only the mic and turning off the internal mic, there are no more problems with feedback.